# How to unit test Subject with a debounceTime in angular

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

One of my component has RxJs subject with a debounce time like below

```
 search = new Subject<string>();
 ngOnInit() {
   this.columnSearch = this.search
     .pipe(debounceTime(400), distinctUntilChanged())
     .subscribe((value) => {
       const columnName = this.params.filterParams.colDef.field;
       const searchData = {
         [columnName]: value,
       };
       this.filterColumns(searchData, this.params.listType);
     });
 }
```

I tried to write spec for the above function like the below

```
 describe('#ngOnInit', () => {
    it('should call the init', fakeAsync(() => {
      spyOn(component, 'filterColumns').and.callThrough();

      component.ngOnInit();
      tick(400);

      expect(component.filterColumns).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
  });
```

Which shows an error like  `Expected spy filterColumns to have been called.` I am not sure is this the correct way to test a subject.Can anyone tell me how to unit test the subject with an debounce time. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test would work, if `this.search` emitted a value:

```
// Does not contain a value yet!
search = new Subject<string>();
```

Therefore the pipe that includes `debounceTime` is never triggered.
The rest of your test setup with `fakeAsync` and `tick(400)` and the spy definition is correct.

It's not completely clear to me what you are trying to achieve, but at some point you have to call `component.search.next(someValue)` to make your test work.